# Get window title with AppleScript in Unicode

Tags: unicode, window, applescript, title

I've stuck with the following problem:
I have a script which is retrieving title form the Firefox window:

```
tell application "Firefox"
   if the (count of windows) is not 0 then
       set window_name to name of front window
   end if
end tell
```

It works well as long as the title contains only English characters but when title contains some non-ASCII characters(Cyrillic in my case) it produces some utf-8 garbage. I've analyzed this garbage a bit and it seems that my Cyrillic character is converted to the Utf-8 without any concerning about codepage i.e instead of using Cyrillic codepage for conversion it uses non codepages at all and I have utf-8 text with characters different from those in the window title.

My question is: How can I retrieved the window title in utf-8 directly without any conversion?
I can achieve this goal by using AXAPI but I want to achieve this by AppleScript because AXAPI needs some option turned on in the system.

**UPD:**
It works fine in the AppleScript Editor. But I'm compiling it through the C++ code via *OSACompile*->*OSAExecute*->*OSADisplay*
I don't know the guts of the AppleScript Editor so maybe it has some inside information about how to encode the characters

Comment: Could you give an example web address? I´ve just tried your script on every Website that came up for a `site:ru` google search and it seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: Do you execute it in the AppleScript Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer when wrote update. Sometimes it is good to ask a question for better it understanding :)
So for the future searchers: If you want to use unicode result of the script execution you should provide **typeUnicodeText** to the *OSADisplay* then you will have result in the UTF-16LE in the result *AEDesc*